# Get all categories and posts in those categories

Tags: categories, wp-query

I am looking for a solution that allows me to print the following:

```
Cat 1        Cat 2        Cat 3
 Post 1       Post 1       Post 1
 Post 2       Post 2       Post 2
 Post 3                    Post 3
                           Post 4
```

**EDIT**

I am looking for something that will only require *one* database query! So if you have a `foreach` in your code followed by a `new WP_Query` then that is not what I am looking for (I am planning to put this onto my website's homepage).

Comment: downvoted as your requirement turns this from a WordPress question into a php sorting problem.

Comment: Please see my answer. Extremely quick and efficient. See the stats I've added in my answer

Comment: How about by this? **<?php 
       $erer = wp_list_categories('orderby=name&title_li=&show_count=1');
       var_dump($erer);
        ?>**  You can get how to use HTML and css then.

Answer (score 20):

**EDIT REVISIT NO 2**

I have never touched the [Transient API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), until today when I saw @MikeSchinkel answer in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/912/31545). This inspired me to revisit this post once again. After some testing, I came up with the following:

- Time to execute went down from ~0.07 seconds to ~0.002seconds
- Database query time went down by about halve
- With the transient, only 2 db queries are executed

How the code works (Just going to discuss changes from the original code from **REVISIT**):

**STEP 1**

We need to save the value of `$q` to a transient, this is the value that holds the category list with post titles.

**STEP 2**

We first need to check if a transient exists, and if none exists, create the transient. If the transient exists, retrieve its info

**STEP 3**

This info is now be passed through a `foreach` loop to print the list with category names and post titles.

**STEP 4**

As it stands, the transient will be updated every twelve hours. This can be set to suite your needs. However, the transient will need to be deleted and recreated every time a post's status changes. This might be from draft to publish, a new post being published or a post that's being trashed. To do this, you need to make use of [`delete_transient`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_transient) which will be hooked to `transition_post_status` which will be triggered each time a post's status changes

Here is the complete code:

In your functions.php

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'publish_new_post', 10, 3 );

function publish_new_post() {
   delete_transient( 'category_list' );
}
```

In your template where you need to display your list

```
<?php
if ( false === ( $q = get_transient( 'category_list' ) ) ) {

    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args); 

    $q = array();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 

        $query->the_post(); 

        $a = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() .'</a>';

        $categories = get_the_category();

        foreach ( $categories as $key=>$category ) {

            $b = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';    

        }

        $q[$b][] = $a; // Create an array with the category names and post titles
    }


    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

set_transient( 'category_list', $q, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
}

foreach ($q as $key=>$values) {
        echo $key;

        echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($values as $value){
                echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    }


?>
```

**REVISIT**

I recently came up with a very lightweight solution that is way much faster than the other possible solutions given. On my test site I get a total generation time of only ~0.07 seconds and only 6 db queries according to [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) while the other methods give me a generation time of ~0.35 seconds and 50 extra db queries.

Here is a breakdown of my method

**STEP 1**

You first need to create a custom query with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to retrieve all published posts

```
$args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);   
    $q = array();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 

    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Step 2**

Using [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category), retrieve a list of all categories a post belongs to.

```
$categories = get_the_category();

        foreach ( $categories as $key=>$category ) {

            $b = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';    

        }
```

**STEP 3**

Assign variables to the post title and the categories of the post

```
$a = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() .'</a>';
```

and

```
$b = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
```

**STEP 4**

Combine these two variables to form a multidimensional array

```
$q[$b][] = $a;
```

To see what is happening in the array, simply do a `var_dump`

```
?><pre><?php var_dump($q); ?></pre><?php
```

**STEP 5**

Using `foreach` loops, create your post list sorted by category

```
foreach ($q as $key=>$values) {
    echo $key;

    echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($values as $value){
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

**ALL TOGETHER NOW!**

Here is the complete code

```
<?php

    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);   
    $q = array();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 

        $query->the_post(); 

        $a = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() .'</a>';

        $categories = get_the_category();

        foreach ( $categories as $key=>$category ) {

            $b = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';    

        }

        $q[$b][] = $a; // Create an array with the category names and post titles
    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

    foreach ($q as $key=>$values) {
        echo $key;

        echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($values as $value){
                echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: why other categories are duplicated?

Comment: How can I do it with custom post type?

Comment: @Pieter-Goosen Excellent code! Instead of using a <ul>, I want to use a template from a file. I tried including the file in the `foreach ($values as $value) {include(template.php);} but then it sets the post names as the page title, instead of the post titles. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add my solution that derived from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271213/use-transient-api-to-cache-queries-for-all-posts-in-all-categories) I had. This caches the query for the categories and also caches the posts, including the post content, in each category. The first time the cache is filled there are normal database queries, however once filled the cached categories and posts are served, so no more database queries.

```
// Transients API all categories and all posts
$query_categories = get_transient('cached_categories');
if ( false === $query_categories){
    $args_cat = array(
        // order by category name ascending
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        // get only top level categories
        'parent' => 0
    );
    // Instead of caching a WP Query I cache 'get_categories()'.
    $query_categories = get_categories($args_cat);
    // var_dump($query_categories);
    set_transient('cached_categories', $query_categories, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
}

// Full posts query
// if there are categories filled with posts
if (!empty ($query_categories) && !is_wp_error( $query_categories )) {

    foreach ($query_categories as $category) {

        // var_dump($category);
        $query_category_posts = get_transient('cached_posts_' . $category->slug );
        if ( false === $query_category_posts ){

            // Query all posts by slug inside each category
            $args_category_posts = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                // The category slug and category name we get from the foreach over all categories
                'category_name' => $category->slug
            );

            // Here I cache the WP_Query, though this runs for all categories.
            // Because of that the '$category->slug' is used to serve a string and not an object.
            $query_category_posts = new WP_Query($args_category_posts);         
            set_transient( 'cached_posts_' . $category->slug , $query_category_posts, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
        }

        if ($query_category_posts->have_posts()) {
            while ($query_category_posts->have_posts()) {
                $query_category_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <article class="<?php echo $category->slug ?>-article">
                    <h2 class="<?php echo $category->slug ?>-article-title">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <p class="<?php echo $category->slug ?>-post-info">
                        <?php the_time('d. m. Y') ?>
                    </p>
                    <div <?php post_class() ?> >
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </article> <?php
            }
        } // end loop
    } // end foreach
wp_reset_postdata() ;
} // end if there are categories filled with posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for getting the categories and the posts within those categories as one result.

My example is based on custom post type taxonomy category `document_category` and the custom post type `documents`. But i'm sure you will get the idea.

```
$result = [];

$categories = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => 'document_category'
] );

foreach ( $categories as $index => $category ) {
    $args      = [
        'post_type'      => 'documents',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'public'         => true,
        'tax_query'      => [
            [
                'taxonomy'         => 'document_category',
                'field'            => 'term_id',
                'terms'            => $category->term_id,
                'include_children' => true
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $documents = get_posts( $args );

    $result[ $index ]['category']  = $category;
    $result[ $index ]['documents'] = $documents;
}

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

**try now this code**

```
$cat_ids=array();
foreach (get_categories() as $cat)
{
    array_push($cat_ids, $cat->cat_ID);
}
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', array('category__and' => $cat_ids) ) );
if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        echo the_title();
    endwhile;
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this... Set the amount of posts you need...

Also I have put it all inside a div, so you can do the structure and design your looking for.

```
<?php  
    $allcats = get_categories('child_of=0'); 

    foreach ($allcats as $cat) :
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 3, // set number of post per category here
            'category__in' => array($cat->term_id)
        );

        $customInCatQuery = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($customInCatQuery->have_posts()) :
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<h3>'.$cat->name.'</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
            while ($customInCatQuery->have_posts()) : $customInCatQuery->the_post(); ?>

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
            endwhile; 
            echo '</ul></div>'; 
        ?>

<?php
        else :
            echo 'No post published in:'.$cat->name;                
        endif; 
        wp_reset_query();
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, but take the example of say 10 categories. In that case your code causes 11 SQL queries. I am looking for 1 SQL query. The best thing would probably be to get all posts, ordered by category, but I don't know how to do that (I didn't find `order_by = cat` in the codex) !?

Comment: i dont think it matters one bit if its 10 categories or 20... (tried it with 20) unless you are trying to load a huge number posts which in any case might slow the page load.. try it - you'll find it real breezy - trying to rearrange after loaded via categories would mean building a huge and mostly useless code (to my humble opinion :) )

Comment: No it doesn't, you just need to change the output slightly (i.e. end list for cat n, and start list for cat n+1) everytime a post has a category that is different from the previous post's category... A lot simpler than bombarding your poor database with 20+ queries per pageload... (to my humble opinion :)

Comment: i think it would we asking the database the same question but just ordering stuff differently on the output end.. i dont see the difference... besides - its a logical query.. "give me the first * from this category"... give me the first * from that category" instead of give me that post, again, again, again.. its the same way but i am puling the data in the way i need it... unless i am mistaken..

Comment: The difference is the number of db queries. One big vs. many small... ;)

Comment: hmm.. dont know - dont understand it to this extent.. i mean the way wordpress acts on this query.. but. i tried and i think it work really fast. i hope i at least shortend the way to your desired solution. ;)

Comment: O(n) inefficient

Answer (score -1):

I've build something for me that I use quite alot, here is the code, you can use slugs, ids or the term object in the `$categories` array, if you want to get all the categories you can use [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms), and feed with a bunch of term objects, but be careful, there is no treatment for hierarchy on this code.

```
$categories = array( 1, 'slug', 3 );
echo '<ul>';
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $term = ( is_numeric($category) || is_object($category) ? get_term( $category, 'category' ) : get_term_by( 'slug', $category, 'category' ) );
    $args = array(
        'cat' => $term->term_id
        // Add any other arguments to fit your needs
    );
    $q = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $q->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'category' ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a><ul>';
        while( $q->have_posts() ) {
            $q->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul></li>';
    } else {

    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: O(n2) inefficient

Answer (score -1):

Untested, yet one of the simplest approaches I would try is the following:

```
<?php
    $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
    foreach ($category_ids as $values) {
        $args = array('category' => $value);
        $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ($posts_array as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?> 
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_query();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Same problem as Sagive's code

Comment: ok.  There is no way to get a single query done.  Loading any page for Wordpress has multiple queries as it is, before adding custom code.  All built-in queries use the WPDB class.  The only way to do it in a single query is with your own transact sql or by making WPDB a parent class to another class for this purpose and calling it that way.

Comment: Nota that `get_all_category_ids();` is now depreciated

Comment: O(n) inefficient

Answer (score -2):

if you are looking for a plugin, [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/other_notes/) might work for you.

Fore a query, take a look at [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Comment: or this too: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_all_category_ids

Comment: Thx, but that doesn't help.