# Create multiple sections for all categories and then queries all the posts for each of those categories

Tags: wp-query, categories, loop

I'm trying to find to find a way to create a loop that queries all categories and then the posts under those categories. I am using a custom loop to display my posts and I'd like to have it follow that same loop. The loop I am using is:

```
<?php 
    // BEGIN LOOP
    if(have_posts()) :

    // Get the initial array with random numbers
    $randomArray = getRandomNumbers();

    // Open the initial row.
    echo '<div class="row">';

        // CHECK FOR POSTS
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            // CREATE ROWS

            if (count($randomArray) < 1) {
                // Close the row and start a new one:
                echo '</div><div class="row">';
                // Get a fresh array with random numbers:
                $randomArray = getRandomNumbers();
            }

            $nextRandomNumber = array_pop($randomArray); // This takes the next number.


            // CREATE RANDOM COLUMN 
            echo '<div class="col-md-' . $nextRandomNumber . ' col-lg-' . $nextRandomNumber . ' post clearfix"><article class="entry-content">';

            // FETCH THUMBNAIL
            echo "<figure><a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>";
            if ( $nextRandomNumber == "6" ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'img-responsive pull-left')); 
            }
            elseif ( $nextRandomNumber == "8" ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('thumb-image', array('class' => 'img-responsive pull-right')); 
            }
            elseif ( $nextRandomNumber == "3" ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); 
            }
            elseif ( $nextRandomNumber == "4" ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); 
            }
            echo "</a></figure>";


            // FETCH TITLE
            echo "<h2><a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</a></h2>";

            // FETCH PUBLISHED DATE
            echo "<span>Published " . get_the_date() . "</span>";

            // FETCH POST'S CATEGORY
            foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo "<h6>In <a href='/wordpress/category/". $category->cat_name . ' ' . "'>" . $category->cat_name . ' '."</a></h6>"; };
            // echo "<h6>In " . $category[0]->cat_name . "</h6>";

            // FETCH CONTENT
            the_excerpt();
            echo ' <div class="entry-meta clearfix"><a href="' . get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )) .'" class="topic-tag">'. get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ) .'</a><nav><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here is some amazing content. It is very engaging. Right?"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></a><a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Like"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a> <a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Add to favorites"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></nav></div></article></div>';

            // END
            endwhile;

        // Close the final row.
        echo '</div>';

    // CLOSE LOOP
    endif;
?>
```

I found a post that does pretty much what I want: [Get all categories and posts in those categories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/get-all-categories-and-posts-in-those-categories). I'm just unsure how I go about adding in my custom loop into the loop to get all the categories and it's post. How I'd like to queries the posts is like so:

```
[query each category]
<div class="bb-item">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container scroller">
            [display custom loop for posts]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
[end query for each category]
```

I'm still fairly new to PHP and WordPress theming so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I figured out to get each section for the categories the way I want it but I'm still unsure on how to add in my custom loop for the posts. Any help is still greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution. Ended up querying each categories using "foreach" and inserting my custom function into the loop. Not sure if it's the best approach but I got it to work so eh. No one else seems to want to help.