# Display post list within category list sorted by name

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, categories

I'm trying to display a list of categories sorted by name and all posts of each category inside it. Like this:

- **Category A** 
  Post B
  Post F
  Post Z
- **Category B** 
  Post A
  Post C
  Post G
- **Category C** 
  Post D
  Post E
  Post H

I managed to display categories list, but it is only sorted by post names, like this:

- **Category B** 
  Post A
  Post C
  Post G
- **Category A** 
  Post B
  Post F
  Post Z
- **Category C** 
  Post D
  Post E
  Post H

  This is my code:

  ```
  $args = array('post_type' => 'projetos');
  $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {echo $category->cat_name . ' ';} ?><br>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>
      <?php
      endwhile;
  }

  wp_reset_query();

  ?>
  ```

How can i sort it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Well, it seems the following approach is a bit DB consuming. Pieter Goosen [posted a very interesting alternative](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145960/31545). Since this approach has already been accepted as a correct answer I don't know, it it is possible to mark this question still as a duplicate. I flagged my answer so a moderator might have a look. Thanks.

---

I first collect all data in an multidimensional array. The subarrays are the categories.

So, I first load all categories with `get_categories()`. They are ordered by title. I load all of them into `$post_categories` while the array key is the ID of the category. The category information like the name will be stored in `$post_categories[ category_id ]['cat']`.

After this I run the query, but I make sure, it is ordered by title. Now, I get all the categories the post is attached to and I save the post in `$post_categories[ category_id ]['posts']`.

Now I have an multidimensional Array, which I just output with two `foreach()` loops.

```
$args = array( 
        'type' => 'projetos' 
    );
    $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
    $post_categories = array();
    foreach( $all_categories as $category )
        $post_categories[ $category->term_id ]['cat'] = $category;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'projetos',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc' 
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()){ 
            $my_query->the_post();
            $p = array();
            $p['permalink'] = get_the_permalink();
            $p['title'] = get_the_title();
            foreach( get_the_category() as $category )
                $post_categories[ $category->term_id ]['posts'][] = $p;
        }
    }

    foreach( $post_categories as $cat ){
        if( ! isset( $cat['posts'] ) || count( $cat['posts'] ) == 0 )
            continue;
        ?>
        <strong><?php echo $cat['cat']->name; ?></strong><br />
        <?php 
        foreach( $cat['posts'] as $post ): 

        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $post['permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a><br />
        <?php endforeach;
    }

    wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: returned this "Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array"

Comment: thats odd. it doesnt so for me. can you tell me in which line?

Comment: i just added
$p = array();
before
$p['permalink'] = get_the_permalink();

and it works perfect now. thank you sir!

Comment: You need to set $p to an array before adding elements to it.

Comment: Yes, thats actually better :) I've updated this in my code above.

Comment: This can get quite expensive to run. You should look into using transients here. See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145960/31545)

Comment: Yes it's seems to bee too expensive to run, when i add more than around 15 posts many of them disappear. Gonna try the transients solution

Comment: Can't get your solution to work @PieterGoosen , nor comment on your answer. Does it support custom type post? Nothing happens

Comment: @ArturHaddad just add the `post_type` parameter to the query arguments, like `'post_type' => 'name of your custom post type'`. `WP_Query` by default uses `post` as the default value to `post_type` :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Now it works great displaying the categories list and posts but the categories are not name ordered. I added "'orderby' => 'title','order' => 'asc'" to the $args then it order the posts by name but not the categories. How can i order the categories by name?

Comment: `asort( $q )` @ArturHaddad

Comment: asort didnt work well but ksort($q) did. Thanks a lot Pieter, great skills