# Custom post type - list posts based on meta_key and display them divided by CPT taxonomy category

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

Shortly:

1. I've custom post type called 'produkty'
2. Inside this CPT I've taxonomy called 'kategorie_produktow' with terms (list of product categories, like in normal posts) - each product has ONE category
3. Inside this CPT I've custom field called 'produkt_nowosc' - it is used to describe the product as newest in offer
4. I'm using a custom page template to display all CPT with 'product_new' set as 'tak' (yes)

To display posts describe above I'm using normal WP_Query():

`$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'produkty', 'meta_key' => 'produkt_nowosc', 'meta_value' => 'tak', 'posts_per_page' => -1) ) ;`

It works perfect for displaying all products, with every product category (taxonomy and term).
`[product 1] [product 2] [product 3] [product 4]`

Now I'd like to separate each CPT taxonomy, it's term and display posts with `produkt_nowosc` set to `tak` like this:

`Post category 1`:

`[product 1] [product 2] [product 3]`

`Post category 2`:

`[product 4]`

What type of query should I use?

Comment: You can try [this approach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145960/31545). Just a note, this uses built in categories and the deafult posts, so you will need to modify the code accordingly

Comment: Thank you Pieter! I've changed the code to matche the custom post type and taxonomies and voila! http://pastebin.com/xKBepGQz

Comment: You can post your code and what you did as an answer and accept your own answer. The are a badge for this as well :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen - oh, I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code, rewriten from posts and categories to custom post types and taxonomy terms.

Thanks to @PieterGoosen for providing the first version.

http://pastebin.com/xKBepGQz

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'produkty', // your CTP name
    'meta_key' => 'produkt_nowosc', // custom meta key for displaying, in my case: the newest product in offer
    'meta_value' => 'tak', // field above set to 'yes'
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);  
$q = array();

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    // displaying the content of product box etc.
    $a = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() .'</a>';
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'kategorie_produktow', $args );
    foreach ( $terms as $term) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        $b = '<span>'.$term->name.'</span>';    
    }
    $q[$b][] = $a;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
foreach ($q as $key=>$values) {
    echo $key;
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($values as $value){
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 for posting your solution. You would want to have a look at transients as I have described in the linked answer as this can get quite expensive to run :-)