# Need help with category listing!

Tags: posts, categories, get-children

I'm trying to solve this for a while, but I couldn't get a satisfactory way to get what I want.
Maybe it's very simple and I'm just too inexperienced.

I need a way to display all the article titles of the child categories of a given category, like this:

```
Category "x"
  Subcategory 1xa
    Post 1xa
    Post 2xa
  Subcategory 2xb
    Post 1xb
    Post 2xb
Category "y"
  Subcategory 1ya
    Post 1ya
    Post 2ya
  Subcategory 2ab
    Post 1yb
    Post 2yb
etc
```

I really can't do this using my limited knowledge. All I could get was child category listing (without the post titles) or a listing of every category, subcategory and posts. I want to get every categories, child categories and the posts come under them( except uncategorized ones), as in the above order.
I saw many posts, but didnt got a solution since I'm not well in coding.

Could anyone help me with this? Thank you very much in advance!

```
<?php

$cat_args = array(

    'show_option_all'  => '',
    'orderby'          => 'name',
    'order'            => 'ASC'
 );

 $categories = get_categories( $cat_args );

 foreach( $categories as $category ) {

     $args = array(

         'showposts'       => -1,
         'category__in'    => array( $category->term_id ),
         'caller_get_posts'=> 1
     );

     $posts = get_posts( $args );

     if( $posts ) {

         echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';

         foreach($posts as $post) {

             setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

             <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p> <?php

         } // foreach($posts
     } // if ($posts
} // foreach($categories
?>
```

Comment: Show us what you've got so far _a.k.a_ include your code. :)

Comment: @TwerkingN00b I have added the code. please help.

Comment: `caller_get_posts` was depreciated in ancient times. Just after the dinosaurs got extinct, it was changed to `ignore_sticky_posts`. BTW, your code is extremely expensive to run

Answer (score 0):

I would first put all parent categories into one array – then run through that array and get all child categories and their respective posts.

So you could basically build a loop 'around' your loop – first loop only queries to a depth of 1 (parent cats) and then the second loop looka a lot like yours, but has the "cild_of" argument. So in this second step you get the child cats and their posts for each parent cat.

```
// First get all parent cats

$parent_cat_args = array(
    'depth'   => 1,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);

$parent_cats = get_categories($parent_cat_args);
```

and then for each parent…

```
// then get all child cats and their posts

$child_cat_args = array(
    'child_of' => $parent_cat_id,
    'orderby'  => 'name',
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);

$child_cats = get_categories($child_cat_args);

foreach($child_cats as $category) {
    $args = array(
        'showposts' => -1,
        'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
    );

    $posts=get_posts($args);

    if ($posts) {

    // …

    }
}
```

You'll find more details about this over at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

Comment: `caller_get_posts` was depreciated in ancient times. Just after the dinosaurs got extinct, it was changed to `ignore_sticky_posts`. BTW, your code is extremely expensive to run

Comment: thanks @PieterGoosen – for my excuse: I basically just copied the OP's code… BTW: what 'cheaper' alternative would you suggest? ;)

Comment: You can look into something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145960/31545), which is in actual fact a good duplicate to the question ;-)