# wp_query is showing posts from other categories

Tags: wp-query, categories, loop

I am trying to make a custom loop that will display the latest 5 posts from select categories, all using a single query. I want the loop to display the category name followed by the 5 posts, and then the next category, etc.

I followed [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/get-all-categories-and-posts-in-those-categories/#answer-145960) and it seems to do what I want, except it doesn't output the categories properly.

For example, let's say I want to display categories 100,101,102 and 103, it should display like this:

`100
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
Post 4
Post 5`

`101
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
Post 4
Post 5`

etc.

---

## The Problem

**However**, currently, if there is a post in category 100, and also in category 250, it will also display the title of category 250 too, like so

`250
Post 1`

How do I get it that it ONLY displays the categories specified?

---

Here's the code I have so far, based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/get-all-categories-and-posts-in-those-categories/#answer-145960).

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            // arguments for your query
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' =>  'id',
            'terms' => $selected_categories, // $selected_categories contains an array of post IDs.
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);   
$q = array();

while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 

    $query->the_post(); 

    $a = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() .'</a>';

    $categories = get_the_category();

    foreach ( $categories as $key=>$category ) {

        $b = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';    

    }

    $q[$b][] = $a; // Create an array with the category names and post titles
}

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

foreach ($q as $key=>$values) {
    echo $key;

    echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($values as $value){
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Custom Select Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) to gather all information in a single call and hope it may work out.

```
global $wpdb;
$selected_cat_id = '6,7,8,9';
$post_count = 5;

$custom_query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->terms.name FROM $wpdb->posts  
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ($selected_cat_id))
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date ASC";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($custom_query, OBJECT);

$cat_posts = array();
foreach($pageposts as $post){
    $cat_posts[$post->name][$post->ID] = $post->post_title;
}

foreach($cat_posts as $key => $values) {
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( $key );
    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category_id).'">'.$key.'</a>';
    $values = array_slice($values,0,$post_count,true);
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($values as $post_id => $value){
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post_id).'">' . $value . '</a></li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Karthick, but I want to do this using only ONE wp_query. Your code is going to run a new query for every category.

Comment: @Edegist Answer has been modified to get result in a single query. You can give a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that worked great! I never really used $wpdb before, so I don't really know whats going on, but it works. Also, If I want to include a template for each post instead of using <ul> and <li>, I'm assuming I need to use `setup_postdata( $post );` but that didn't seem to work, as the template loads with blank data. e.g the post titles etc aren't loading.

Comment: Also, using Query Monitor, it seems like this code generates around 30 queries to the db if I call 3 categories (with 5 posts each).

Comment: @Edegist it is returning 30 columns of data because the MySQL query is having LEFT JOINS with category table. Still you can filter the query and get only whatever column needed. I have updated the answer slightly to get only 3 columns - $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->terms.name

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! I tried using `$post = $post_id; setup_postdata($post);` and my template file now loads, but the first item that shows up shows the title and link of the current page, and not the title and link of the first post. Do you know how I can change that? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use 'category_name' as direct argument in your $args array, not inside your tax_query array. I always displayed posts of a category on my pages in that way.