# Display category title and three latest post inside the category

Tags: categories, loop

I am looking for something very similar to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63092/display-one-latest-post-from-multiple-categories). However, the answer provided there seems strange to me. I don't know what the arguments `posts_per_page=-1` and it seems more like a hack to me than an actual solution.

I tried the following, which loops the first 6 categories and it works great. However, I want to exclude some categories from this, for instance 1 and 4. I am not entirely sure how to approach this.

```
<div id="category-posts-content">

    <?php $i = 0; while ($i < 7) : ?>
        <?php query_posts('cat='.$i.'&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <div class="subject">
                    <h3><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>            
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
       <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

NOTE: some posts belong into more than one category!

Comment: Is this a custom template or **category.php**?  Also, you shold never really use `query_posts()` - create your own custom query using the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class.

Comment: @DavidGard This snippet will eventually be output inside `single.php`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @DavidGard *never really use* is wrong and not strong, it should be *never use*, period. :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen - I'll make sure I make the statment **IN CAPS AND BOLD** next time :)

Comment: Hahaha, don't have to be so harsh though :-) @DavidGard

Comment: @PieterGoosen Now calm down y'all, we've got a question to solve here. :D

Comment: :-) Already busy writing up an essay. Halfway done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posts_per_page=-1` is perfectly fine. This is used to get all posts. As for your code, you should never ever use `query_posts` unless you want to intensionally break stuff on your pages. This is one of the most common functions used and yet the one function that causes the most problems in a website.

I have recently done a post on custom queries and have included many important links to important posts that you **have to** read, including why you should never use `query_posts`. You have stated in your previous question that you need to learn a lot, well, this post and the linked ones should be a great learning curve :-). Please check it out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545).

What I find extremely odd about your code is that you are using a counter for category ID's. This is really unpredictable, because all tags, categories and custom taxonomy terms and post formats share the same tables, so the ID's are not sequential for a given taxonomy. You should rather make use of [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)  to gt an array of all the categories. More reliable, and you have the `exclude` parameter to exclude categories and the `include` parameter if you only need specific categories

You will need to run a separate query for every category. This can be quite resource intensive, so you might want to look at putting the results in a transient (check [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145960/31545)) or a cache.

You can try something in the line of this:

```
$categories = get_categories(array('exclude' => '4, 7'));

foreach ($categories as $category) {

    $args = array(
        'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    );
    $q = new WP_Query($args);
    while($q->have_posts()) {
        $q->the_post();

        //your template tags and HTML mark up

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

### EDIT

Just a last note, something that I have initially missed, you only do one `while()` loop, not two as in your question :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I one slight change in my code, `the_post()` should be `$q->the_post()`

Comment: After fiddling around I got it to work! Question though, why is `wp_reset_postdata();` inside the foreach loop? Or, more precisely, does it matter whether it is inside foreach or out?

Comment: I like to reset every query, say you have 4 categories, that means 4 queries. To avoid that one query might influence the next, I reset every one, that is why my `wp_reset_postdata()` is inside the loop. I caught your comment before you edited it :-), you can use `echo $category->name` just before your loop to display the category name

Comment: Ah, I see. Haha, darn it. Figured it out moments after I posted that comment and didn't want to come on as stupid or lazy, so I edited that part out. Too late I guess. Thanks again, works great!

Comment: One is never stupid, just eager to learn. :-) Glad it worked out for you